# Calculating % of total within groups across each column and transposing

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to create the following output (assuming a lot of IDs and a lot more attributes)?
I am stuck after calculating the % of total by ATT1 within ID and then ATT2, etc.. Not sure how to go about making the rows into column headers and aggregate.

Input File (df in R):

```
ID  ATT1    ATT2    ATT3    ATT4    Value
1      a       x       d       i    10
1      a       y       d       j    10
1      a       y       d       k    10
1      b       y       c       k    10
1      b       y       c       l    10
2      a       x       c       k    20
…
```

And I want the output file to look like (ATT4_l is cut off):

```
 ID ATT1_a  ATT1_b  ATT2_x  ATT2_y  ATT3_d  ATT3_c  ATT4_i  ATT4_j  ATT4_k   
  1  0.6     0.4     0.2     0.8     0.6     0.4     0.2     0.2     0.4    
 ...
```

I tried using dplyr

```
df %>% group_by(ID, ATT1) %>% mutate(proc = (Value/sum(Value) * 100))
```

But I am not sure what to do once I have all the ATT calculated to get them into columns and aggregated so that each ID only has 1 row of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the two main workhorses of the `tidyverse`: `dplyr` for calculations and `tidyr` for reshaping data. Some of the reshaping is convoluted so I'm breaking it into steps.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
...
```

If you `gather` the data from its original wide format into a long format, you'll have a column of IDs, a column of ATTx values, a column of letters (don't know the context meaning of these, so I'm literally calling it `letters`), and a column of values. From this format, you can group observations by combinations of ID, ATT, and letter, and you can later stick ATTs and letters together in the way you've laid out.

```r
df %>%
  gather(key = att, value = letter, -ID, -Value) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      ID Value att   letter
#>   <int> <int> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1     1    10 ATT1  a     
#> 2     1    10 ATT1  a     
#> 3     1    10 ATT1  a     
#> 4     1    10 ATT1  b     
#> 5     1    10 ATT1  b     
#> 6     2    20 ATT1  a
```

After grouping, calculate total values for each ID/ATT/letter combo:

```r
df %>%
  gather(key = att, value = letter, -ID, -Value) %>%
  group_by(ID, att, letter) %>%
  summarise(group_val = sum(Value)) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID, att [3]
#>      ID att   letter group_val
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>      <int>
#> 1     1 ATT1  a             30
#> 2     1 ATT1  b             20
#> 3     1 ATT2  x             10
#> 4     1 ATT2  y             40
#> 5     1 ATT3  c             20
#> 6     1 ATT3  d             30
```

Using `mutate`, you can calculate the share of each observation within its larger group. `mutate` drops one layer of the grouping hierarchy, so this is the share of values for each letter within a given ID and ATT. Since you no longer need the total values, just their shares, drop that column, and stick the ATTs and letters back together with `unite`.

```r
df %>%
  gather(key = att, value = letter, -ID, -Value) %>%
  group_by(ID, att, letter) %>%
  summarise(group_val = sum(Value)) %>%
  mutate(share = group_val / sum(group_val)) %>%
  select(-group_val) %>%
  unite(group, att, letter, sep = "_") %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>      ID group  share
#>   <int> <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 ATT1_a   0.6
#> 2     1 ATT1_b   0.4
#> 3     1 ATT2_x   0.2
#> 4     1 ATT2_y   0.8
#> 5     1 ATT3_c   0.4
#> 6     1 ATT3_d   0.6
```

Now you have all the information you're looking for, just need to get it into a wide format, turning the values in the `group` column into individual columns. You do this with `spread`:

```r
df %>%
  gather(key = att, value = letter, -ID, -Value) %>%
  group_by(ID, att, letter) %>%
  summarise(group_val = sum(Value)) %>%
  mutate(share = group_val / sum(group_val)) %>%
  select(-group_val) %>%
  unite(group, att, letter, sep = "_") %>%
  spread(key = group, value = share)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID ATT1_a ATT1_b ATT2_x ATT2_y ATT3_c ATT3_d ATT4_i ATT4_j ATT4_k
#>   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1    0.6    0.4    0.2    0.8    0.4    0.6    0.2    0.2    0.4
#> 2     2    1     NA      1     NA      1     NA     NA     NA      1  
#> # ... with 1 more variable: ATT4_l <dbl>
```

Note that there are `NA`s filled in here where there aren't observations for combinations of ID/ATT/letter. I'm assuming you'll have more complete data than in the sample you posted.

<sup>Created on 2018-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and steps! a lot of new things I have learned, unite, spread etc. Also things like using the - sign before ID and Value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `reshape2` package

```
library(reshape2)

df.new <- dcast(df,
                formula = ID~ATT1,
                value.var = "proc",
                fun.aggregate = mean)
```

This will not completely fix your problem though - I recommend doing this first to make your data tidy

```
df.tidy <- melt(df, 
                id.vars = c("ID","Value"),
                variable.name = "ATT1_4",
                value.name = "att.factor")
df.tidy <- df.tidy %>% group_by(ID, att.factor) %>% mutate(proc = (Value/sum(Value)*100))
df.new <- dcast(df.tidy,
                formula = ID~att.factor,
                value.var = "proc",
                fun.aggregate = mean)
```

NaN will be returned for anything combination that isnt represented in df.tidy. you can use the `fill` argument to assign a value to those.

Comment: Thanks, I am not familiar with reshape2 library, and I am struggling with this part:           value.names = "att.factor"   The 2nd part of your code %>%  group_by(ID, att.factor) %>% .. is throwing an error saying "Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `att.factor` is unknown"

Comment: Just FYI, `reshape2` is being deprecated in favor of `tidyr`: https://github.com/hadley/reshape

Comment: @Lulumocha, the error may have been that `variable.names` and `value.names` should not have had the s at the end. I took out the spelling mistake and it should work now.
@camille Thank you, I did not realize this.